# When performing wash sale calculations does time of day matter?

Tags: united-states, calculation, wash-sale

For wash sales, I've read there is a 30-day window both before and after an opening trade during which a loss from a closing trade becomes a wash sale with respect to the opening trade's cost basis calculation.

Does the time of day matter? Put another way, is the wash sale window calculated as ±30*24*60*60 seconds before/after the opening trade or is the time of day irrelevant and the date is just the opening trade's date ±30 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, time of day doesn't matter. Its the whole day, it doesn't matter if you sold in the morning or bought in the evening.